# Trajectory Tracking of URDF/ROS model in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have a made a URDF model of a robot and currently spawning it in Gazebo. I have used diff_drive_controller to spawn it. Now, I want to track the model in a particular trajectory. Are there any tutorial available on internet? Can anyone help me regarding this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300959/trajectory-tracking-of-urdf/ros-model-in-gazebo/) by [Maulik_Bhatt](https://answers.ros.org/users/35533/maulik_bhatt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2018-08-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-20**:
With "tracking", do you mean:

1. keep track of where the robot has been (and draw a line or something similar)
2. control where the robot should go, using a path with changing positions over time

**Comment by [Maulik_Bhatt](https://answers.ros.org/users/35533/maulik_bhatt/) on 2018-08-20**:
Hello, With tracking I meant I should be able to control where the robot should go, using a path with changing positions over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I meant I should be able to control where the robot should go

the common approach for this would be to first setup the [navigation stack](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation). If/when that is working, and you really want to dictate a path (ie: not give a destination and have the robot figure it out by itself) search ROS Answers for Q&A's about how to send a sequence of goals to `move_base`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maulik_Bhatt](https://answers.ros.org/users/35533/maulik_bhatt/) on 2018-08-20**:
Thank you for the help.